# One word for a non-dating relationship?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for when two people really like each other, but aren't dating, don't want serious relationship?

### EDIT

No, they aren't involved at all. They do not engage sexually with each other.

Comment: You may be looking for [platonic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/platonic); close but not sexually-involved.

Comment: There is a lot of words synonym of "friend", e.g. companion, partner, intimate, mate, soul mate. To get appropriate responses, your question  should be more precise.

Comment: @Graffito I meant as more than just a friend. But not that more.

Comment: Platonic is the word.

Comment: As indicated by @AndrewLeach - a "platonic relationship" seems to be the best fit, refering to love without sex. If you need less than "love", you may say "mutual affection". (*affection is a feeling of liking and caring for someone*).

Answer (score 4):

You're describing a ***platonic*** relationship.

> **platonic**
>
> (Of love or friendship) intimate and affectionate but not sexual:
>   *their relationship is purely platonic
>
>   platonic love*
>
> [[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/platonic)]

Answer (score 0):

If sex is involved, the word you are looking is a *fling*.

> : a brief sexual relationship

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fling)

"I had a fling with this girl from Paraguay... it lasted two weeks, but it was amazing."

However, this is answering without knowing the specifics such as the length of the relationship.

Comment: Is it? You have sex while you are not dating? That is closer to rape.

Comment: People hook up all the time, are you serious? @Rathony You don't have to be dating to have a one night stand, for example. Or a fling, in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

If they like each other, try to meet whenever they can, and there is no sex at all, it's just **friendship**.

You could also they

> they are **"as thick as thieves"**
>
> - to be very ​close ​friends and ​share ​secrets [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/be-as-thick-as-thieves)
> - A special bond people have for each other. [UD](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=thick+as+thieves)
> - (Of two or more people) very close or friendly; sharing secrets [OD](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/as-thick-as-thieves)

"Mary, Tom, and Sally are as thick as thieves. They go everywhere together." "Those two families are thick as thieves."